# How to serialize an object to a xml or a json stream asynchronously?

Tags: .net, json, xml, async-await

I know the two most typical serializers for resp. xml and json in .NET:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer?view=netframework-4.7.2
- https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm#JsonSerializer

The great thing is that they can both write to a stream, but none of them can do that asynchronously.

The only workaround I found is to perform a custom serialization using the XmlWriter / JsonWriter and write the element / attributes by hand...

Is there any existing solution out there that could do the same without having to resort to these two writers?

Comment: The source is available, it would just require tweaking [JsonSerializer](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonSerializer.cs) and [JsonSerializerInternalWriter](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/JsonSerializerInternalWriter.cs) and you could make your own branch with a `Task SerializeAsync(TextWriter textwriter, object value)` method.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain thanks a ton! Sadly seems there is nothing similar for xml serialization. Anyway thanks again!

Comment: Actually, just found [this](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_WriteToAsync.htm) no need to write your own methods.

Comment: [XmlSerializer](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml/System/Xml/Serialization/XmlSerializer.cs,292c7197dcb706a1) source is also available (but much more complicated).